Why would `Doc2Vec` work?
My experiment with Doc2Vec didn't yield good results. It prompts me to thinking why it works at the first place. Intuitively, Word2Vec works because of many repetition of similar word patterns. For document vector, if it sees many similar topic articles, e.g. sports article, I would think it may learn something related to the general sports topic. But it may not be able to distinguish the nuances among the different articles. I'd like to hear your opinions on this.
